# High-performance bitmap marshaling for DLL

Tags: delphi, dll, bitmap, marshalling, zxing

My idea is to make a DLL out of Delphi version of ZXing. The library operates with bitmaps with high frequency. The maximum frequency is the webcam frame rate, but I would do it a bit less frequent using a timer, say 3 times per second.

I would like to keep webcam code outside of the DLL.

Now there is the question how to pass the bitmap to the DLL. The obvious thing is to save/load it to memory stream. Theoretically there will be an excellent compatibility, but how about performance? I predict a high marshalling overhead. Is there something faster in Windows for passing bitmaps over the DLL edge?

```
TForm1 = class(TForm)
private
  _bmp: TBitmap;
end;

procedure TForm1.BarCodeTimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Pass the _bmp bitmap to the DLL here
  // Here is the cutting line. The code below should be in a DLL
  var ReadResult := _scanManager.Scan(_bmp);
  try
    if ReadResult <> nil then begin
      // Got the bar code
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(ReadResult);
  end;
  // End of DLL code
end;
```

Comment: A DLL share the memory space of the executable having loaded it. You can simply pass a pointer to the data. If you use run-time packages for both the DLL and EXE, then you can even simply pass the object reference (A variable of type TBitmap). No need to marshall anything nor pass thru file I/O.

Comment: fpiette, thank you very much! And what if someone would like to use the DLL from C++ or C# code?

Comment: If the DLL has to be used from C++ and C# code, you can still pass a pointer to the memory holding the bitmap. But the bitmap must be in a format that the other languages understand, not a TBitMap object which is specific to Delphi and C++Builder. I suggest you pass a simple array of RGB (3 bytes per pixel) values as well as the width and height of the bitmap.

Comment: The global variables of a DLL exist separately for each application. If the Dll is used in an application over several routes, the global variables can be changed for all routes via each route. If the application is started multiple times, each application has its own global variables that the other application does not know about.